# Random crash on LGE Nexus 4 when inflating com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView

Tags: android, inflate-exception, nexus-4

Please help. I'm receiving a bunch of app crashes on our crashlytics pointing to this error. But I can't replicate this bug. And based on the crashlytics data, it only happens on LGE Nexus 4 running Android 6 (Marshmallow).

Here's how I inflate the PhotoView:

```
<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
            android:id="@+id/pvSampleId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/LBL_SAMPLE_ID"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/img_sample_id" />
```

Below is the crash log:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #182: Error inflating class com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.java)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onActivityCreated(Fragment.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchLowMemory(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.allocBackStackIndex(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeShowHideFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```